# Use PostGIS binary function on all possible pairs

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a table with ids and geometries. I am trying to return all ids which are intersect with another id.

My best query that I managed to arrive to:

```
SELECT a.id, b.id
FROM t1
WHERE st_equals(a.geom, b.geom) IS FALSE AND ST_intersects(a.geom, b.geom);
```

For example:

| ID | geometry |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0103000020E6100000010000000500 |
| 2 | 1103000020E6100000010000000500 |
| 3 | 2103000020E6100000010000000500 |
| 4 | 3103000020E6100000010000000500 |
| 5 | 4103000020E6100000010000000500 |
| 6 | 5103000020E6100000010000000500 |
| 7 | 6103000020E6100000010000000500 |
| 8 | 7103000020E6100000010000000500 |

The desired result:
{1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7,8}

Comment: You were almost there, but didn't define what "a" and "b" were (plus ST_Equals is a *really* expensive way to test identity (and technically wouldn't work, since it could return True on records other than a.id == b.id)). Next time, please include the error generated by your query.

Answer (score 1):

Join the table to itself on intersects, where id's are not the same:

```
select a.id a_id, b.id b_id
from public.opbuff a
join
public.opbuff b
on st_intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
where a.id<b.id
```

[image]